# Chunking Arithmetics

Tags: theory, organization

Consider two coordinate systems, one for the objects themselves, one for the chunks the objects are contained in. Let's consider a chunk size of 4, meaning that the object at coordinate 0 is in chunk 0, the object at coordinate 3 is also in chunk 0, but the object at coordinate 8 is in chunk 2 , the object at coordinate -4 is in chunk -1.

Calculating the chunk number for an object with a positive position is easy: `object.number/chunk_size`

But I do not find a formular that calculates the correct chunk position for objects at negative positions:

`-4/4 = -1` is correct but `-2/4 = 0` is not the required result, though `-4/4 -1 = -2` is now incorrect, but `-2/4 -1 = -1` is now correct ...

Is there a sweet, short way to calculate each position, or do I need to check 2 conditions:

```
chunkx = objectx > 0 ?
    objectx / chunksize :
    objectx % chunksize == 0 ?
        objectx / chunksize :
        objectx / chunksize - 1;
```

Alternative:

```
chunkx = objectx > 0 || objectx % chunksize == 0 ?
    objectx / chunksize :
    objectx / chunksize -1;
```

On a side note: calculating the position of an object within the chunk is:

```
internalx = objectx - chunkx * chunksize
```

for both positive and negative (-4 -> 0 ; -2 -> 2; 1 -> 1; 4 -> 0)

Is there a more elegant way to calculate this that I am blatantly overseeing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to convert your numbers to floating point and have a cheap floor function you can use floor(-1.0/4.0) to get -1 as you wish, but the conversion to floating point may be more expensive than the branch.

Another option is to work with positive numbers only by adding a large enough number (multiple of chunk size) to your object coordinate, and subtracting that number divided by the chunk size from your chunk coordinate. This may be cheaper than a branch.

For your second question, if your chunk size happens to be a power of 2 as in your example you can use binary and (-1 & (chunksize-1) == 3)

Answer (score 0):

If your chunk size is a power of two you can do:

```
chunkx = (objectx & ~(chunksize - 1)) / chunksize;
```

If the chunk size is also constant the compiler can probably turn that into a trivial AND and shift. E.g.,

```
chunkx = (objectx & 3) >> 2;
```

For the general case, I don't think you can eliminate the branch, but you can eliminate the slow modulo operation by offsetting the number before division:

```
chunkx = ((objectx >= 0) ? (objectx) : (objectx - (chunksize - 1))) / chunksize;
```